# Prove $\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}} +\sqrt{\frac{x+z}{x+y+z}} + \sqrt{\frac{y+z}{x+y+z}} \le \sqrt{6}$

Tags: inequality

I have this exercise from a book I have been making my way through.

Let x,y,z be positive real numbers. Prove the following: $$\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}} +\sqrt{\frac{x+z}{x+y+z}} + \sqrt{\frac{y+z}{x+y+z}} \le \sqrt{6}$$

I thought that I may be able to use Cauchy's inequality to answer this question, but after a few attempts I'm not getting anywhere meaningful. I know that since clearly $x + y < x + y + z$, then $\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{x+y+z}}$ must be less than one. I tried repeating with the other fractions and proved that the once the fractions are summed up it must be less than three, but that's all I've managed to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

edit: Turns out you can use Cauchy's inequality to solve it. Let $b_1, b_2, b_3 = 1$. Then let $a_1 = \sqrt{\frac{x+y}{3(x+y+z)}}$ $a_2 = \sqrt{\frac{x+z}{3(x+y+z)}}$ $a_3 = \sqrt{\frac{y+z}{3(x+y+z)}}$ This leads to the solution.

Comment: Hint: 1) LHS is homogeneous in $x,y,z$, you only need to look at the case $x + y + z =1$. 2) [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality)

Comment: Hey, I recognize this book! Is it from *The Cauchy-Schwarz Master Class*? If so, use the "1-trick" to prove this inequality using cauchy's inequality

Comment: It is from the book 'A concise introduction to pure mathematics' by Martin Liebeck. And thank you, I managed to solve it using cauchy's inequality, I was just slightly off at the start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a convexity result. Let :
$$a = \frac{x+y}{(x+y+z)}$$
$$b = \frac{x+z}{(x+y+z)}$$
$$c= \frac{y+z}{(x+y+z)}$$
The square root is concave :
$$\sqrt{\frac23}=\sqrt{\frac13 a + \frac13 b + \frac13 c} \geq \frac13 \Big(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b} + \sqrt{c}\Big)$$
Which gives the result.

EDIT :
Concavity of $f$ implies that $f$ is above every function :
$$\Delta_y(x) = \frac{f(x) -  f(y)}{x - y}$$

[image: 1]

Comment: Thanks, I don't entirely understand your answer as I haven't covered these convexity results yet, but setting a, b and c equal to the square root of the values you chose and applying cauchy's inequality led me to the answer. Wouldn't have spotted that without your answer, much appreciated.

Comment: I will draw something.

Answer (score 1):

We can assume $x+y+z= 1$ and by AM-GM inequality:
$\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}\cdot (1- x)} \le \dfrac{\frac{2}{3}+1- x }{2}$. Do it again for $y,z$ and add up . The sum is $2$ which is the right side.